# DocAI, How to extract circled information from PDF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I'm wondering how I can ONLY extract the information that's framed and have it labeled by the processor.

Would training a form parser on multiple files with frames make it extract only the information in that's in the frame?

[Chart with framed information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIAUY.png)

I tried using a form parser, but it extracts all the information from the chart.